# I am trying to create a map figure in python using Plotly but my data is not being imported or it is not properly working

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f7o9.png)

I am trying to get multiple data from the .csv file, but it is not working.
I tried using a .csv file that only contains the iso_alpha column, and that one is working.
How can I get all my data to show?

Comment: please add the code as formatted code not a screenshot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the separator character for the csv file

```
data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lys4nder/SchoolDataset/main/data_project_full.csv', sep=';')
```

Comment: thank you! this fixed it. you saved me!